# Mongoid 2.4 Querying For Embedded Document By Id Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

We have a model Entry with an embedded Item:

```
class Entry
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Spacial::Document
  embeds_many :items, cascade_callbacks: true
...

class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Spacial::Document
  embedded_in :entry
...
```

If i query mongo directly for an entry by item id:

```
{"items._id" : ObjectId("50536b18baa072000f000360")}
```

It returns the Entry:

> 505363b36181ce00020006b1
>   {"created_at":"2012-09-14T17:04:51Z","items":[{"_id":"50536b1a2b17b3...

Yet when i query via Mongoid:

```
irb(main):002:0> Entry.where('items._id' => '50536b18baa072000f000360')[0]
=> nil
```

All other queries work (for other fields on items and for fields on entry). But not for id.

We're running mongoid (2.4.12).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently you have to wrap the ID in BSON::ObjectId(), so:

```
Entry.where('items._id' => BSON::ObjectId('50536b18baa072000f000360'))[0]
```

Otherwise mongo will sporatically not return the result.

Comment: Or in my case, `Moped::BSON::ObjectId('50536b18baa072000f000360')`, in order to cure `undefined method \`__bson_dump__' for BSON::ObjectId`. Whew!

Comment: Use Moped::BSON::ObjectId in Mongoid 3

Answer (score 5):

This works with Mongoid 4.0.0.beta1:

```
Entry.where('items._id' => BSON::ObjectId.from_string('50536b18baa072000f000360'))
```

Here is the link to the documentation.

http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/BSON/ObjectId.html#from_string-class_method

Answer (score 0):

`Entry.where('items._id' => Moped::BSON::ObjectId('50536b18baa072000f000360'))[0]`
see the documentation [here](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/BSON/ObjectId.html#from_string-class_method)

Answer (score -3):

Alternative, this will also work.

```
Entry.find('50536b18baa072000f000360')
```